# Append nodetext to svg element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg

I would append a textnode to a `g` svg element.

Nothing is being printed on screen when I trigger `my function`

But it workd when I append `TextNode` element directly to body

```js
function myFunction() {
  var g = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
  var t = document.createTextNode("Hello World");
  document.body.appendChild(g);
  g.appendChild(t)
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to create a Text Node.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

This code works without using `g`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var g = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
  var t = document.createTextNode("Hello World");
  document.body.appendChild(t);
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to create a Text Node.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Create a SVG <text> element, not a HTML text node. The MDN SVG reference has a good overview of all SVG elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a text element as well and append everything to an svg element.
In this case I use an svg element with a viewBox that allows me to see the text although I didn't set any values for the x and y attributes. Depending on your viewBox you may need to set those attributes too.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var g = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
  var text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
  text.textContent = "Hello World";
  g.appendChild(text);
  svg.appendChild(g);
 
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to create a Text Node.</p>

<svg id="svg" viewBox="-100 -50 200 100" width="200"></svg>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```